# Proof something with multivariate normal distributions

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $X \sim N(\theta, \Sigma), X\in \mathbb{R}^p $, I need to prove

$$p(x) \propto \exp \{-\frac1 2 x^T\Sigma^{-1}x + x^T\Sigma^{-1}\theta\} $$

I can I do this?

I know that the density should be

$$ p(x) = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^{n/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det \Sigma}} \exp \{(x-\theta)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\theta) \} $$

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we see that
$$
p(x)\propto \exp\left[(x-\theta)^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}(x-\theta)\right]
$$
and if we expand what's inside the brackets, we get
$$
\begin{align}
(x-\theta)^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}(x-\theta)&=x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}x+\theta^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta-x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta-\theta^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}x\\
&=x^\intercal \Sigma^{-1}x+\theta^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta-2x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta
\end{align}
$$
since $x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta=(x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta)^\intercal=\theta^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}x$
(remember that $\Sigma$ is symmetric). Therefore, we conclude that
$$
p(x)\propto\exp\left[x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}x-2x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta\right]\propto\exp\left[-\frac12 x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}x+x^\intercal\Sigma^{-1}\theta\right].
$$